# centos 6.4 command line issue?

Tags: linux, centos

I am new to CentOS.

My problem is the command line in centos is strange. I can use up arrow to view only one the previous command, but I cannot view more than one (in ubuntu, I can do it by press up arrow multiple times). I only can view more than one command by using "history".

Another thing is I cannot edit previous command as normal (Like I press up once, then adding more parameter by just typing more words). In centos, once I press up, it shows the command, then I have to press "i" to use the insert mode to edit the command, "x" to delete a character etc. that is so annoying for me because I am familiar with ubuntu. However I used to work on other centos 5 but I never seen this problem.

How to make it like ubuntu command line mode?

Thanks.

Comment: can you set "export HISTSIZE=1000" in your .bashrc? I never use Centos but I expect this to be there. Than you logout and login again

Comment: This sounds like "vi mode."  Can you try "set -o emacs"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve, adding "set -o emacs" to ~/.profile fix my issue.